# Not exists between two different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I came across one sql query where NOT exists is being performed in between two different tables like below.

```
SELECT PDS.FILE_SUBID
       PDS.ACCT_NUM
       PDS.VALUE
  FROM PdsTable PDS

 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT PCS.ACCT_NUM FROM
        PcsTable PCS
        WHERE PDS.ACCT_NUM = PCS.ACCT_NUM
        AND PDS.OPT_VALUE = 5000
        )
```

I understand when `WHERE PDS.ACCT_NUM = PCS.ACCT_NUM` is happening SQL engine must be doing INNER JOIN to get similar ACCT_NUM from both tables, but what about this parameter (`PDS.OPT_VALUE`) in inner query ? This column dont even exists in PcsTable table.

May I know please how this query or this type of logic works in sql ?

My Assumption says: To use PDS.OPT_VALUE = 5000 in inner query, before that inner join type of condition should be applied like WHERE PDS.ACCT_NUM = PCS.ACCT_NUM. Is it correct or wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: indeed i know that i blindy copy pasted also the `IN` statement @MarmiteBomber

Comment: `NOT EXISTS(...) / EXISTS(...)` should ideally be used with boolean values like true, false, 1 and 0.. So better is to use ... `NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ...)` for example it also stops a extra (random) (memory|disk) I.O seeks to the PCS.ACCT_NUM data

Comment: @RaymondNijland `select true` is also not valid syntax, the top efficient way is to use `exists (select NULL..`, but the *readibility and understandability* are bit low...

Comment: indeed i didn't work with Oracle database for some time now.. mine comment was more meant in the general sense across multiple database vendors.  @MarmiteBomber

Answer (score 1):

Note that `NOT EXISTS IN` is not valid SQL, so I assume the `IN` is a typo.

The query is saying "override" the `NOT EXISTS` comparison when `PDS.OPT_VALUE = 5000`.  That is, the record automatically does not exist in this case.

You can write this instead as:

```
SELECT PDS.FILE_SUBID, PDS.ACCT_NUM, PDS.VALUE
FROM PdsTable PDS
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM PcsTable PCS
                  WHERE PDS.ACCT_NUM = PCS.ACCT_NUM
                 ) OR
      PDS.OPT_VALUE = 5000; -- <<< this predicate is very probably wrong and should be: nvl(PDS.OPT_VALUE,0) != 5000
```

The logic of your query is quite confusing.  If the `opt_value = 5000`, then the subquery returns no rows.  And, `not exists` will return the outer record.  That is regardless of whether or not there is a match.

I find this version much clearer.  I am not a fan of putting such conditions in the subquery.  I think they make it harder to understand.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, Do you think so your query will perform same as mine ? Because What am thinking is, If we use PDS.OPT_VALUE = 5000 inside subquery than we'll get ACCT_NUM having PDS.OPT_VALUE not equal to 5000 but in the query you have shared it will give us the records having PDS.OPT_VALUE = 5000...Am I wrong or correct ?

Comment: @Andrea . . . The logic with `NOT EXISTS` is complicated.  I think the logic is write.  There are more opportunities to optimize this version; further, it could be split into two different subqueries using `union all` and appropriate indexes defined for each.  But actually, the further optimization probably wouldn't make a big different, so the two versions would probably have similar performance behavior.

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . I usually use `1` because it is easy to type (and I changed this in the answer).  However, `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS` is checking for the existence of *rows*.  Many databases do not even evaluate the `SELECT` expressions, to the point that fatal errors are not even generated.  Oracle should be smart in this respect.

Comment: You might be right that many database with `EXISTS/NOT EXISTS` do not physical fetching the matching records and `... NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 ....)` might be convert into some kind of count query which checks the existence of rows.. It would be a fun study in the source code of the open source databases to check that it is really doing.

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . This is way off topic for this question, so perhaps you want to ask another question.  However, consider that this works:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=183261f7f976369d3a8f894aba160e0d.

Comment: " This is way off topic for this question, so perhaps you want to ask another question. " it's not mine question.. @GordonLinoff .. "However, consider that this works" or `not exists (select 1 - 1 ...)` or the even more wierd `not exists (select 0 / 1 ...)`

Answer (score 0):

They are all logical statements which return boolean logic. While `PDS.ACCT_NUM = PCS.ACCT_NUM` returns `true`, `PDS.OPT_VALUE = 5000` returns `true` too, and those are combined with an `and` which means both conditions return `true` at the same time. So the subquery returns `true`.

Just like the query uses `PDS.ACCT_NUM` in the subquery, it also uses `PDS.OPT_VALUE` and `5000` as a constant independent from `PcsTable`, and returns `true` provided `PdsTable` has matching values.

Comment: So you mean they are not filtering the data coming from SELECT PCS.ACCT_NUM FROM PcsTable PCS  ? What type of data Inner query will return which is having PDS.OPT_VALUE = 5000 condition and this column dont even exists in inner query's table ? What's a meaning of writing PDS.OPT_VALUE = 5000 in inner query ?

Comment: @Andrea excuse me, logic was right but using "each table" was wrong.

Comment: I just want to know how PDS.OPT_VALUE = 5000 is working with inner query ? This not even exists in inner query's table like ACCT_NUM does ..! Even if it returns boolean, then there should be something it could relate with inner query, because WHERE PDS.ACCT_NUM = PCS.ACCT_NUM AND PDS.OPT_VALUE = 5000 is going to implemented on inner table only ..!

Comment: @Andrea Yes, sure it works provided `OPT_VALUE` equals `5000` for `PdsTable`, but independent from `PcsTable`

Comment: Am I correct that,While doing NOT EXISTS clause table do gets joined on one key(for ex: PDS.ACCT_NUM = PCS.ACCT_NUM ) but column belongs to only outer query table can be used as filter clause in inner query ? Secondly, Am I correct that for NOT EXISTS, at least one COMMON key condition is must for ex WHERE PDS.ACCT_NUM = PCS.ACCT_NUM where tables could get a point to relate each other ...!

Comment: @Andrea yes, you're totally correct for both oy your sentences.

Answer (score 0):

I'd read the query as follows:

Get from the `pds` all rows with `ACCT_NUM` that **doesn't exist** in `pct`, for rows with `ACCT_NUM` that **exist** in `pct` get all rows except those with `PDS.OPT_VALUE = 5000`.

**Explanation**

1) If  `ACCT_NUM` from `pds` *doesn't* exist in `pct`, the subquery can not return a row, so `NOT EXISTS` is `true`.

2)  If  `ACCT_NUM` from `pds` *does* exist in `pct`, the first predicate is true, so the second `PDS.OPT_VALUE = 5000` **must not be true** so that the subquery returns no row.

So basically you *filter* row with `PDS.OPT_VALUE = 5000` and all other values (incl. NULL are passed.

Small example

```
create table pds as 
select 1 acct_num, 4999 OPT_VALUE from dual union all
select 1 acct_num, 5000 OPT_VALUE from dual union all
select 1 acct_num, null OPT_VALUE from dual union all
select 2 acct_num, null OPT_VALUE from dual;

create table pcs as 
select 1 acct_num  from dual;


select * from pds
where NOT EXISTS (SELECT PCS.ACCT_NUM FROM
        PCS
        WHERE PDS.ACCT_NUM = PCS.ACCT_NUM
        AND PDS.OPT_VALUE = 5000
        )
order by 1,2;

  ACCT_NUM  OPT_VALUE
---------- ----------
         1       4999 
         1            
         2
```

`ACCT_NUM=2`  all rows passed, as 2 not in `PCS`

`ACCT_NUM=1` OPT 4999 and NULL passed, but 5000 filtered as 1 in `PCS`.

It is much more clear to *re-formulate* the Query pushing the second predicate out of the subquery:

```
select * from pds
where NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM
        PCS
        WHERE PDS.ACCT_NUM = PCS.ACCT_NUM
        ) OR
    nvl(PDS.OPT_VALUE,0) != 5000 
order by 1,2;
```

The result is the same.